# cx_Freeze won't compile Python3 scripts on Ubuntu, better solution?

Tags: ubuntu, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I'm trying to compile a fairly large script written in Python 3 to an executable, on Ubuntu 13.04 64bit, and cxfreeze installed from normal reps.

I have the dependencies installed (python3-dev, python3-pip libffi-dev).

Executing like below, does compile the script, but however, it does it in Python 2.7.

```
$ cxfreeze <script>
```

Any attempt to compile Python 3 fails on Ubuntu. I tried this by means of the setup.py script and importing cx_Freeze module in assistance:

```
$ python3 setup.py build
```

And the content of the setup.py script:

```
from cx_Freeze import *

setup(
name = "py3Script",
version = "1.0.0",
description = "py3Script",
executables = [Executable("py3Script.py")])
```

I did try on Fedora, but only managed to execute the compiled on Fedora only - it didn't like being executed on Ubuntu.

Could I get some advice for the best ways of getting the script compiled so it could work on any Linux distribution equally well?

Thank you.

Comment: The cx_Freeze package in Ubuntu is only the Python 2 version. You'll need to install it from source for Python 3. http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @thomas - your comment that doesn't help - you've just repeated the question.

Comment: @BerryTsakala : well, the questioner didn't seem to understand that the package in the repositories is for Python 2. I know it's not a complete solution, that's why I posted a comment, not an answer.